# How to get informations about checkboxes from ReyclerView in fragment

Tags: java, android

I need to get informaions about item from recyclerView. I try do something like this to get in but this didnt work, any ideas?? I think that calling CheckBox is useless and i dont need it. but now i dont have any idea how to do it.

```
private void handlerForChannels() {
    list = ChannelsManager.getInstance().getChannelList();
    mAdapter = new SettingsCustomAdapter(context, posit, list);
    verticalGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    textView.setText(R.string.title_channels);
    button.setText(R.string.select_all);
    final SparseBooleanArray mChecked = new SparseBooleanArray();

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAdapter.getItemViewType(SETTINGS_CHANNELS);
            mAdapter.getItemId(getId());
            CheckBox cb;
            int count = list.size();
            cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_for_recycle);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                mChecked.put(i, cb.isChecked());
            }


            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
    button.setNextFocusLeftId(R.id.select_all);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    button1.setText(R.string.cancel_text);
    button1.setNextFocusLeftId(R.id.select_all);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ((MainActivity) activity).closeSettingsDrawerFragment();
        }
    });
    button2.setText(R.string.ok_text);
    button2.setNextFocusLeftId(R.id.ok_button);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think need to call a adapter and getting everything from items, but how?

Comment: I want to make buton for select/deselect all items. 
My app looking like: http://imgur.com/a/HBSin

Button+title is a fragment, and for recyclerview i create new layout with text, checbox. I dont know how to now create function in fragment for  select/deselect all records

Comment: do you just want to select them all, or check which one are selected?

Comment: Yes just select everything. this button is non sense for me but i need to create it.

Comment: @Rodriquez Just set true for boolean variable of model class like we did in last que and notify it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new Array into your adapter with booleans, to set the checkboxes true or false:

```
    //...
    public ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxesState;
    //...

    public mAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> posit, ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<Boolean> checkBoxesState /* <- add this one*/) {
        //...
        this.checkBoxesState = checkBoxesState;
    }
```

Than you set if they get checked or don't:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotaViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        //...
        viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxesState.get(position));
    }
```

Now you probably already know how to check them but for those who stumble into this too, here's how:

```
    //create adapter
    mAdapter = new mAdapter(context, posit, list, checkBoxesStates /* <- fill with false booleans */ );
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //check them all
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= mAdapter.getItemCount(); i++) {
                checkBoxesStates.add(i, true);
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0); //this updates the adapter
            }
        }
    });
```

**Edit:**

You have to create your checkbox in the ViewHolder, something like this:

```
        public class NotaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        //...
        CheckBox checkBox;


        public NotaViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //...

            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowCheckBox);

            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference
ON
viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(checkBoxesState.get(position));

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do this:
1. in your adapter add some code:

```
private boolean isAllCheckBoxSelected;

public void setAllCheckBoxesSelected(boolean isSelected){
isAllCheckBoxSelected = isSelected;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
...
holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(isAllCheckBoxSelected);
...
}
```

2. in your fragment call where you need

```
mAdapter.setAllCheckBoxesSelected(true or false);
```